# UITabBar button without a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

Was wondering if any of you tried to add a UITabBarItem to UITabBar that functions as a button that opens safari Externally. Meaning it would not be a real tab, but just used as a button.
Does Apple reject apps for using the UITabBarItem like so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, my question is specific to UITabBarItem. I know that I can use URL schemes but can I use them with tabBar buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not reject tabBar button that opens Safari externally.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a view controller for that tab and then in the <strike>`viewDidLoad`</strike> `viewDidAppear` method add in your URL Scheme to load up safari or whatever app you need to open.

I see no reason why Apple would reject it. All the tab bar really is, is just a UI preference.

Comment: I would put it in viewDidAppear if you opted for this solution